# Calculating the expectation of random exponentioal function using correlation information

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving

Let us assume that the two random variable $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi)$.
In addition, the correlation ratio between them is defiend by $\rho$, i.e., $E[XY^*]=\rho$. In this case, can we calculate the following expectation?
$$
\begin{align}
    E[e^{jX-jY}]
\end{align}
$$
by using $\rho$ information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no way. The correlation is not enough, you need to know the joint distribution.